# Make Sharp Toggle

Tags: edit-mode

Is there a way to toggle the sharp edges in edit mode? The bright color and dimensions obscure all other edges when in top, end, back, bottom, etc. ortho views.  -Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the *Sharp* edges's highlight visibility toggle checkbox in the Properties bar (<kbd>N</kbd>) under the *Mesh Display* section

[image]